# Edit input parameters in swagger UI dynamically via code

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to clear all the path & query parameters in my swagger UI when the user click on the clear button.

I didn't find any built in option for it so i wrote javascript file that adding event listener that remove the the input form like this:

```
var allDivInputs = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('input');

    for (i = 0; i < allDivInputs.length; i++) {
        allDivInputs[i].value = '';
    }
```

It deleted the text from the input in the UI but when execute the api again it send to service with the old parameters that now empty in the UI.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its may be because the are just removed from the view.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it right?

Comment: What [version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) of Swagger UI do you use - 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: version 3. The swagger open source is written in react and i figured it saved states so the attempt to edit it from outside using javascript is not valid solution. I already opened new issue in git for this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5283